# structural, acumulative or generative recursion drracket

Tags: recursion, racket

```
(define (sqrt/nat x)
  (local [(define (sqrt/above x t)
            (if (> (* t t) x)
                (sub1 t)
                (sqrt/above x (add1 t))))]
  (sqrt/above x 1)))
```

I need to decide if that code uses either structural, acumulative or generative recursion.

I think ith either acumulative or generative recursion. For me it can be both. I just dont understand the difference between these two recursion types.

am grateful for any help

Comment: 1. does it accumulate? it increments the accumulator parameter, but it does no agglomeration of the final result from parts it is given (like summing up numbers in a list). so perhaps not. 2. does it generate? yes, it generates new guess at each step. 3. does it follow a structure of its argument, analyzing it and deconstructing it and solving a sub-problem recursively? no, it does not break its argument number into any two smaller parts. (that's guessing the meaning of the terms you used, as you haven't given us a reference to the material you're following in your studies).

Comment: re 1. OTOH the typical "length of list" function will repeatedly increment its accumulator parameter while advancing along the input list, so maybe, still, yes as well.